# JSF 2.0 - which version of Facelets is shipped?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

Since todays 2.0 jsf implementation ship with facelets, I'm wondering which version they actually are including.

So basically, which facelets version ships with mojarra 2.0 or myfaces 2.0?

This question arose basically when going through [the richfaces migration guide](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333AndJSF20) which is suggesting in context of using jsf 2 together with richfaces 3.3.x: "Facelets 1.1.15 should still be used because of dependencies in RichFaces from the Tag Handlers classes." 
Is there an easy way to tell what version is packed? the [official facelets page](http://facelets.java.net/) seems pretty abandoned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSF 2 ships with Facelets builtin. It's basically not a separate project anymore (that's also why the official Facelets page "seems pretty abandoned").

What RF guys is trying to tell you is that you still need to include the old Facelets 1.1.15 JAR file in the classpath next to JSF 2 in order to get the RF 3.3.x tag files to run without dependency troubles.

Comment: can I eventually expect that something breaks using facelets 1.1.15 together with jsf 2?

Comment: No, it's differently packaged. There are no clashes in package/class names.

Comment: So I think JSF 2.x ships with facelets 2.x - a problem which occurred to me was when using facelets 1.1.15 as viewhandler together with tomahawk for jsf 2. Tomahawk comes with the tag library namespace of facelets 2 and results in an error when using with facelets 1.1.15 configurations -> basically I pulled the plug on supporting richfaces 3.3.x since replacing it is more fun than chasing errors resulting by an odd setup.